# function from_tz not working for first day of month

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datetime, oracle11g

I have query which is using FROM_TZ function to convert UTC time to PTC as below.
It works fine for the all the days in month except 1st day.

For Example if run the below query for 1st May Timezone conversion is not happening properly

Query:

````
  SELECT /*+ no_unnest */  
 MIN(TO_CHAR(processstart,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) xlagltrn_min,
 MAX(TO_CHAR(processend,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))   xlagltrn_max,
 MIN(TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(processstart, DBTIMEZONE) at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles','DD-MON-YYYY 
 HH24:MI:SS')) xlagltrn_min_tz,
 MAX(TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(processend, DBTIMEZONE) at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles','DD-MON-YYYY 
 HH24:MI:SS'))   xlagltrn_max_tz,
 MAX(processend) - MIN(processstart) Total
 FROM ess_request_history erh
 WHERE TO_CHAR(erh.processstart,'DD-MM-YYYY')  = TO_CHAR(:p_processstart,'DD-MM-YYYY')
 AND definition LIKE '%XLAGLTRN'
 ```
May 1st Results

XLAGLTRN_MIN      XLAGLTRN_MAX       `XLAGLTRN_MIN_TZ`          XLAGLTRN_MAX_TZ
01-05-2020 05:30   01-05-2020 08:18            01-05-2020 01:00            30-04-2020 23:40

May 2nd Results Time Zone Conversions Working Properly

XLAGLTRN_MIN                  XLAGLTRN_MAX              XLAGLTRN_MIN_TZ        XLAGLTRN_MAX_TZ
02-05-2020 05:30           02-05-2020 08:15            01-05-2020 22:30            02-05-2020 01:15

Thanks
````

Comment: Hello kiks, welcome to stack overflow. It would help a lot if you provided a testcase (create table statements, insert statement) with sample data and the expected outcome of your query.

Comment: Hi Koen, Thank you for the reply.  '01-05-2020 05:30' Data is in UTC which is not converting to PST properly using FROM_TZ function in above query.

Comment: Hi kiks. Yes you posted that in your question too. What do you expect me to answer ? I don't have access to your database and I don't have access to do your data. That is why I'm asking for the testcase.